# What's on Applied Cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

Just wondering what is the story behind the front cover image of Schneier's **Applied Cryptography** book https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/

Who is the author? Is it some famous picture encrypted or there's a much simpler explanation?

Comment: You mean the painting by Mona Mark? https://ahomewithasoul.com/search?page=3&q=mona+mark . I found this by finding the book jacket on Schneier's site, which lists the artist, then googling her work. Took me 4 minutes.

Comment: Oh, my bad, my e-book doesn't include back cover. Thank you!